# Can i run brushless ESC from any digital pin of arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm

{assume arming is done}
Can i connect the brushless ESC to any digital pin and give writemicroseconds() to it? Will this work. because i have connected my 4 ESC's to "~" pins. so i thinks that other will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work.

The [Servo](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Servo) library doesn't use hardware PWM, so you can connect them to a non "~" (PWM) pin.

Comment: Yes, RC servos can be attached to non-PWM pins, but  a “brushless ESC” is not an RC servo but instead  a PWM-controlled Electronic Speed Control for brushless DC motors.